# Inconsistence in calculating zero geometric area

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

First, let us see disk

```
Area[Disk[{0, 0}]]
Area[Disk[{0, 0}, 0]]
Area[Disk[{Quantity[0, "Centimeters"], Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}, 
  Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]]]
```

gives

```
\[Pi]
Undefined
Quantity[0, ("Centimeters")^2]
```

Theoretically, area of a disk with zero radius should be zero. But disk with unit and without unit give different results, especially, `Area[Disk[{0, 0}, 0]]` gives `Undefined`. Why?

then, let us see triangle

```
Area[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}]]
Area[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}]]
```

gives

```
Area[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}]]
Area[Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}]]
```

they just do not give area.

```
Area[Triangle@{{Quantity[0, "Centimeters"], 
    Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}, {Quantity[0, "Centimeters"], 
    Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}, {Quantity[0, "Centimeters"], 
    Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}}]
Area[Triangle@{{Quantity[0, "Centimeters"], 
    Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}, {Quantity[0, "Centimeters"], 
    Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}, {Quantity[0, "Centimeters"], 
    Quantity[1, "Centimeters"]}}]
```

is even worse, they give messages like

> Norm::ptype: The second argument of Norm, {0,0}, should be a symbol,
> Infinity, or an integer or real number not less than 1 for vector
> p-norms; or 1, 2, Infinity, or "Frobenius" for matrix norms.

But the triangle area formula is as simple as

```
Area[Triangle[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]]

1/2 Abs[-x2 y1 + x3 y1 + x1 y2 - x3 y2 - x1 y3 + x2 y3]
```

if three corners are the same, area is zero.

There are two issues here:

- A zero radius disk or a zero area triangle is a point, but it is still a limiting case of a disk or triangle, why not give it an area? If we were writing functions that are involved with geometrical area, that means we have to manually add an if branch for zero area case, that is a very subtle trap.
- Quantity and numeric values often give different results. This is not limited to area calculation. For example, `TriangleCenter[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, "Circumcenter"]` and `TriangleCenter[{{Quantity[0, "Centimeters"],  Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}, {Quantity[0, "Centimeters"],  Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}, {Quantity[0, "Centimeters"],  Quantity[0, "Centimeters"]}}, "Circumcenter"]` give different results

Comment: A zero area triangle can also be a line segment.  Just an observation, it doesn’t address your question.

Comment: @CraigCarter Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Anyway, a line segment is also a legitimate limiting case of a triangle.

Comment: I agree.  Thinking about the disk--perhaps the Undefined is correct and the limit is zero.  If the disk is the set of all points less than a given distance from a point, then it degenerates to a single point (as does a circle) and the set no longer has a 2D measure.  The Quantity, perhaps, is casting it to a numerical value which evaluates to 0.0.  Not sure.